# How to trigger 3rd party api when button onclick?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, custom-button

I want to trigger a 3rd party api when admin clicking on the 'Send Contract'button in Sales Order View.

[image]

This is the code for my button plugin:

```
<?php
  namespace MarsMage\Eversign\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

  use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View as OrderView;

  class View
{
public function beforeSetLayout(OrderView $subject)
{
    $subject->addButton(
        'send_contract_button',
        [
            'label' => __('Send Contract'),
            'class' => __('send-contract'),
            'id' => 'send-contract-button',
            'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $subject->getUrl('module/controller/action') . '\')'
        ],
    );

    $subject->addButton(
        'send_hire_purchase_button',
        [
            'label' => __('Send Hire Purchase'),
            'class' => __('send-hire-purchase'),
            'id' => 'send-hire-purchase-button',
            'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $subject->getUrl('eversign/sendhirepurchase') . '\')'
        ],
    );
}

 }
```

This is the code for my controller:

```
<?php
  namespace MarsMage\Eversign\Controller\Adminhtml;

  use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

  class SendHirePurchase extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
   {
      /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
      protected $resultPageFactory;

     /*** @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
      public function __construct(
         Context $context, 
         \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
          \MarsMage\Eversign\Helper\Data $data
           )
       {
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->helper = $data;
         parent::__construct($context);
          }


       public function execute()
       {
         $this->sendHirePurchase();
        }

       public function sendHirePurchase()
       {
         try {
    
        $postData = [
            
    'sandbox' => 0,
    'template_id' => 'b4edc68efca14b44a6aec31c6a7ad9dd',
    'title' => 'Hire Purchase Agreement',
    'message'=> 'This is my message.',
    'custom_requester_name' => '',
    'custom_requester_email' => '',
    'redirect'=> 'https://myredirect.com/completed',
    'redirect_decline' => 'https://myredirect.com/declined',
    'client' => '',
    'expires'=> 1494276966,
    'embedded_signing_enabled' => 0,
    'signers' => [
        
    [
        'role'=> 'Client',
        'name'=> 'Chris',
        'email' => 'chris@marslab.com.my',
        
        'message' => 'This is my custom message to Paul.',
        'deliver_email' => '',
        'language' => 'en'
    ], 
    
   
],
    'recipients'=> [
    
    [
        'role' => 'Motorkap',
        'name' => 'Motorkap',
        'email' => 'admin@motorkap.com',
        'language' => 'en'
    ],
],
    'fields' => [
        [
        'identifier' => 'full_name',
        'value'=> 'Chris Lee'
        ], 
        
        [
        'identifier' => 'cash_price',
        'value'=> 12000
        ],
]];
        
        $apiKey = "9b735cc49cf593754c8cc54cec2cc71eReset";
        $business_id= "280557";
       $url="https://api.eversign.com/api/document?access_key=" . $apiKey . "&business_id=" . $business_id;

        $this->curl->post($url, $postData);
        // Response Text
        $response = $this->curl->getBody();
        // Response Header
        $responseHeader = $this->curl->getHeaders();
        // Response cookies
        $responseCookies = $this->curl->getCookies();
        return $response;
    }
catch (Exception $e) {
    $return = ["status"=>false, "message"=> $e->getMessage()];
}
  }
    }
```

When I put the url in button onclick, it always return me invalid form key. What is the exact solution to trigger api when button onclick?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct to me, nothing strange.

Maybe you forgot to declare your routes.xml file or maybe misconfig the route file?

Comment: I have declared routes.xml but still it return invalid key when button triggered.

Comment: You can easily check your routes setting by go directly to that route, see if it's handling correctly.

Comment: or you can change the action to Magento's route, any route, if it's working then your route has problem, if it is NOT working, then your button setting has problem